# Non-exist directory and Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, cpython

I'm trying to run the project in github, everything has been good untill I download the requirements through

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

I got this error and some question want to ask, please look at the Terminal Response image first

[Terminal Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq1Hi.png)

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7DSX.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbVZj.png)

I'm using VSCode (with C/C++ extension in it), python 3.11.5

**Question:**

1. There is no such directory call **pip-build-env-34zfhn81** in the error
   '**C:\Users\Long\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-34zfhn81...**'
   and all the below error, you can see it in Image2. How can it still return error when there's no folder or file there.
2. My comuputer currently has Microsot Visual C++ 14 and some other version, you can see in Image1, do I need to remove all other version
3. If don't, how can i fix the problem without installing Microsoft Visual Studio

I have installed Microsoft VS but dont know which package to install in the suggestion, and due to the limit of my C directory memory, I can barely fit few of them

I have asked one of my friend, he cloned the project and work perfectly fine without having to install Microsoft Visual Studio.

In addition, this is the picture of the [project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b3kz.png), the requirement is in the backend folder